# Flurry Analytics with iPhone and Website

Tags: iphone, ios4, flurry

I have an iPhone application that is based on social networking. I have integrated flurry analytics into it. Now, there is a limitation to the information that my client can send to flurry and I want some other information also to be tracked and only my server can provide thatinformation. Can I integrate them both into one for my application. In other words, can I make some JSON calls from my server so that it also adds information to the unique id allocated for my mobile application so that I can see all the information I want in one place on the flurry page of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find a feature missing in Flurry or Flurry forces you to upgrade to their paid plan, you can also consider using the google analytics for ios.

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/

It's free and has event tracking as well, which you can use custom variables with it.

After you set up google analytics, you can use the google gdata library to read any kind of data you need from google using their API.

I wouldn't create my own tracking system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any official ways to do this.  You may ask this question to Flurry support - actually it is a better way to find out.  I think it would be a hack if you sniff the format of the Flurry requests (which are not open, because we do them thru the provided FlurrySDK in iOS apps) and then try to perform the same type of requests on your server side.  I don't even know whether Flurry sends the info plaintext or encrypted - I suppose it is encrypted, so you are gonna have a hard time rev.engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK their public server API is read-only ([link](http://wiki.flurry.com/index.php?title=API_Usage)). I'd say the only way to get what you want is to export the data from Flurry to your own server and then correlate the data there. But of course that means not having Flurry's nice GUI to view the data with, so it might not be what you want.

Comment: We are contemplating that. Simply more effort.